# Product images not getting displayed both in frontend and backend

Tags: magento

I have installed magento version 1.3.2.4. everything works fine except the image upload. Images are getting uploaded successfully and saved in temp folder, but not showing up in both backend and frontend. I cant see anything in small-image folder. Tried renaming htaccess in media folder and tried all the possible changes. flash version am using is 11.1. I would be glad if I can get any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few thing which are worth a shot.

1. Is your caching enabled? If your admin -> system -> cache management
2. Have you cleared your cache? In the same place you can clear it out
3. Have you checked the image url using Firebug or view source? If your url is wrong then you might need to update it in the database, then clear your cache

Comment: thank you for your time and response. I have cleared all the cache and also disabled it from backend. still not working. Image is showing this URL:http://.../foldername/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/135x135/5e06319eda06f020e43594a9c230972d/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg. Can you suggest me which table I can change in?

Comment: I have the same issue where only the images of the last sold products are not being shown in the slider system.